# I have heard meat when offered to Gods or pitrus removed the sin of eating it. How can we do it ritual procedure and if there are any books on it

Tags: rituals, tantra, pitru, meat

Namaskaram. So as I said in above statement in today's world I can't offer a whole goat or a hen to god's like narasimha or Kali. I have to get it from meat shop and offer it. The reason why I'm asking is I'm a vegetarian but my family loves eating meat and they won't quit it. So how to ritualistically offer it to pitrus or gods and what's the procedure in offering the meat also if there are other ways to remove that sin of eating meat through the shastras it would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: That is not possible to do for an ordinary householder without proper knowledge of Vedic and Tantric rituals .. Apart from that one needs to be initiated and qualified to do the sacrifice  .. also one can not do that regularly before every meal. ..

Comment: the problem is  we don't cut meat as per shastras I agree with that.We don't even prepare meat as per the shastras or certain foods as per the shastras, people don't follow pitru paksha too as per the scriptures. Even being initiated into tantric sects I have seen that as a person who's been involved in tantric sampradaya. My guru doesn't offer animal blood to his god he offers either his own blood or cuts an ashgourd because he considers those two are only worth sacrificing . I know how the sacrificial ritual happens but I'm not a butcher. So I need a practice how to serve meat to god easily